# How does quantum contextuality relate to realism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-measurements, foundations, non-locality

According to [Spekkens](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.71.052108) contextuality can be defined as follows:

> Suppose A, B and C are Hermitian operators such that A and B commute,
> A and C commute, but B and C do not commute. Then the assumption of
> noncontextuality is that the value predicted to occur in a measurement
> of A does not depend on whether B or C was measured simultaneously.

Consider the following realistic scenarios

```
ABC x y
+++ + +
++- + -
+-+ - -
+-- - +
-++ - +
-+- - -
--+ + -
--- + +
```

where the first three columns represent the predetermined values of $A$, $B$, and $C$, and the last two represent the products $x = A\cdot B$ and $y = A\cdot C$. If the system is prepared determinstically such that $x = +$ and $y = -$, then we're left with either $ABC = ++-$ or $ABC = --+$ as our pool of pre-determined (i.e. realistic) assignments.

Clearly, a measurement of $B = \pm$ *necessarily* implies $A = \pm$ whereas $C = \pm$ *necessarily* implies $A = \mp$. How is this realistic assignment of values not non-contextual?

Comment: why do you think they are related? I don't see an obvious connection between the two things.

Comment: @glS The example I gave was meant to illustrate the relation between realism and (non-)contextuality.

Comment: this "realistic" assignment is still noncontextual I think. Sure, the random variables are correlated, but it is still true that the outcome probabilities associated to measuring $B$ do not depend on whether you are also measuring $A$ or $C$ at the same time. Of course, *knowing* the outcome of $A$ or $C$ gives you more information, and possibly determines, the outcome of $B$, but that doesn't contradict that the outcome probabilities associated to measuring individual observables do not depend on what else is being measured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to the comment by glS above. The scenario described is in fact non-contextual in the sense that the expectation value of $A$ is independent of whether it is obtained together with $B$ or with $C$.

My question was based on the confusion that, say $P(A=+\mid B=+) = 1$. I misinterpreted the *given that* sign $\mid$ as meaning that the expectation value of $A$ depends on $B$ whereas in reality, all it means is that a particular outcome of $A$ (i.e., $+$) depends on a particular outcome of $B$ (i.e., $+$) with no extra information as to how likely those outcomes are.